# Input while cv2 shows an image

Tags: python, opencv, input

I would like to get input when I am showing an image using OpenCV's `imshow()` function. But If I do so, the image doesn't show correctly and a grey image appears instead.

It works if I use `destroyAllWindows()` command, but is there a proper solution for this?

```py
def write_solution(crop):
    cv2.imshow('Frage',crop)
    ans = input("Antwort: ")
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    return ans
```

Comment: Can you show your code? What kind of input do you want to get? after imshow (e.g. between imshow and your blocking input) you will needa waitKey call. Maybe you will need a mpre sophisticated ui including mpre sophisticated image rendering and jnput stuff.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I m trying to get a string as input.

Comment: Okay, it works, if I swap waitKey () and the input()  function. Thanks!

Comment: waitKey call is the moment when the actual window rendering is performed. If you need a non-blocking rendering, choose waitKey(1) (or in general >0) instead of waitkey (0)

Comment: I would like to vote your comments as useful, but I think I can't. (Guess because I just became a new contributor)

Comment: No problem! Feel free to write and accept your own answer, so others with a similar problem can find it!